# How do I get help for specific package in Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

I installed mysql using homebrew and after the download was complete I was prompted with:

> We've installed your MySQL database without a root password. To secure
>   it run:
>       mysql_secure_installation
>
> MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by
>   default
>
> To connect run:
>       mysql -uroot
>
> To have launchd start mysql now and restart at login:   brew services
>   start mysql Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can
>   just run:   mysql.server start

I do not want a background service so I executed `mysql.server start`

The problem I have is, I will forget these instructions tomorrow, so is there a way to ask HomeBrew about mysql next time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `brew info mysql` which will return:

> ==> Caveats We've installed your MySQL database without a root password. To secure it run:
>       mysql_secure_installation
>
> MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by
>   default
>
> To connect run:
>       mysql -uroot
>
> To have launchd start mysql now and restart at login:   brew services
>   start mysql Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can
>   just run:   mysql.server start